# How to show path and distance on map with leaflet, shiny apps?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I would like to show the distance between two locations using the leaflet package in a shiny app.
I don't know how to do it. A line should connect two points on a map and display the distance on it.
Please find the sample image:
[image: Path with distance]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
library(leaflet)
library(osrm)

route = osrmRoute(c(115.6813467,-32.0397559), c(150.3715249,-33.8469759), overview = 'full')
# route_simple = osrmRoute(c(115.6813467,-32.0397559), c(150.3715249,-33.8469759), overview = 'simplified')
route_summary = osrmRoute(c(115.6813467,-32.0397559), c(150.3715249,-33.8469759), overview = FALSE)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(c(115.6813467,150.3715249), c(-32.0397559,-33.8469759)) %>% 
  addPolylines(route$lon,route$lat, 
               label = paste(round(route_summary[1]/60), 'hr - ', round(route_summary[2]), 'km'), 
               labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE))

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(c(115.6813467,150.3715249), c(-32.0397559,-33.8469759)) %>% 
  addPolylines(route$lon,route$lat, 
               popup = paste(round(route_summary[1]/60), 'hr', br(), round(route_summary[2]), 'km'))
```

I added `route_simple` in the code above but didn't use it. It just saves less points on the route so it's less detailed but runs quicker. Feel free to play around. I also used a popup instead of a label in my second example. You need to click on the route to open it.

**Label Example**
[image: label example]

**Popup Example**
[image: popup example]

If you want a shiny app then see below:

```
library(leaflet)
library(osrm)

route = osrmRoute(c(115.6813467,-32.0397559), c(150.3715249,-33.8469759), overview = 'full')
# route_simple = osrmRoute(c(115.6813467,-32.0397559), c(150.3715249,-33.8469759), overview = 'simplified')
route_summary = osrmRoute(c(115.6813467,-32.0397559), c(150.3715249,-33.8469759), overview = FALSE)

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput('map')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      addMarkers(c(115.6813467,150.3715249), c(-32.0397559,-33.8469759)) %>% 
      addPolylines(route$lon,route$lat, 
                   label = paste(round(route_summary[1]/60), 'hr - ', round(route_summary[2]), 'km'), 
                   labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great help. I changed the coordinates of lat and lon, there I am getting error. I replaced these values c(54.77127, -18.99692), c(54.71064, -18.96314). "Error in gepaf::decodePolyline(res$routes$geometry): Wrong encoded string format". I am not able fix this issue. Could you please find out why it is giving such an error?

Comment: I am not sure as those coordinates work fine for me. Maybe make sure that all your packages are the latest versions.

Comment: Check your versions of gepaf, osrm and leaflet.

Comment: @ Eli Berkow: Great answer! Just a question - what is this br() function? Thank you so much!

Comment: br() is just a line break. Creates a new line.